# cant access multiple indices in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

here is my simple problem.
I have created a numpy array as follows:

```
data_apprx = np.zeros((2, 18), dtype={'names': ('weight', 'trace', 'TD_err', 'count', 'prob', 'code'), 'formats': ('f8', 'f8', 'f8', 'f8','f8', 'f8')})
```

Nowm I wan't to access certain fields in the matrix according to specific indices, for example:

```
data_apprx[0,[0,2]]['count']+= 2
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

```
data_apprx = np.zeros((2, 18), dtype={'names': ('weight', 'trace', 'TD_err', 'count', 'prob', 'code'), 'formats': ('f8', 'f8', 'f8', 'f8','f8', 'f8')})
data_apprx[0,[0,2]]['count']= data_apprx[0,[0,2]]['count'] + 15
data_apprx[0,[0,2]]['count']
Out[67]: array([ 0.,  0.])
```

Why is the result remain zeros?

Comment: Not entirely sure about what you are asking, since you haven't posted any sample output, But have you tried it like `data_apprx[:,[0,2]]`?

Comment: `data_apprx['count'][0,[0,2]] = data_apprx['count'][0,[0,2]] + 15`

Comment: Thanks champ! my bad

Comment: If the records indexing is basic (with slices), selecting the records will work.  But indexing first on the field is generally a good idea.